# Full Calendar - When an event is dropped, how to find the DIV it was dropped in?

Tags: jquery-ui, fullcalendar, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am working on a FullCalendar implementation that does all of the basics, which are working just fine (Drag/Drop, Resize, Add, Remove, Edit Events). However, I've recently integrated a "repeat item" function into my calendar for anniversaries and such. This is all fine as well.

the problem comes in when I have an item (which is repeated, lets say 100 times) that is dragged to a new location. An ajax call is made to update the dates/times on the item in the database, as well as all of the "repeat" items. This can take a few seconds - so I want to essentially show a "loading" GIF in the date DIV the event was dragged and dropped onto. How does one obtain the DIV id or the DIV as an object?

**EDIT**

I would also be open to hearing other alternatives to the loading graphic in the date div, if there is a way around it.

```
$('#jMonthCalendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable:true,
    eventSources: [
        "/api/getCalendarItemsAll.php"
    ],

    eventDrop: function ( event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ){
        updateCalendarItem( event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view, true );
    },
    eventResize: function( event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ){
        updateCalendarItem( event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, null, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view, false );
    },

    //... Other Event Handlers

});

function updateCalendarItem( event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view, isDrop ){

    var j=JSON.stringify(event);
    var url = '/api/calendarUpdateItem.php';
    var data = 'j=' + encodeURIComponent(j) + 
              '&dd=' + encodeURIComponent(dayDelta) +
              '&md=' + encodeURIComponent(minuteDelta) +  
              '&dr=' + encodeURIComponent(isDrop) +
              '&ref=' + randomString(30);

    $.getJSON(
        url, data,
        function(result) {
            refreshCalendar();
            if (result.status == "ERR"){
                showError(result.message);
            }
        }
    );          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had some what of a similar issue except I had options on the page that would load different events to the calendar. Unfortunately I'm not sure how you could do it just for the div that the event it being dropped to, since there really isn't a defining feature of the individual divs.

What I ended up doing was using a jquery plugin called [BlockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) to create a modal over the whole calendar while I was loading new events, it took a little tweaking to get it to fit right over the calendar, but it got the message across. Here's a little code snippet.

```
//this is called when the checkbox is clicked
if(this.value === 'on'){
    $('#mycalendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', '--url--');
    this.disabled = true;
} else {
    $('#mycalendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', '--url--');
}
```

This next part is a parameter of fullcalendar that is called when something needs to unload or completes loading.

```
loading: function(bool) {
    if(bool){
        $('#mycalendar').block({
            message: '<h1>Loading...</h1>',
            css: {top: '10% !important'}
        })
    } else {
         $('#mycalendar').unblock();
         $('.processCheck').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}
```

I know this isn't exactly what you're looking for but I hope it helps anyway!

Comment: This is actually a great idea. A translucent overlay for the whole calendar. While it's more of a "sledge hammer" approach than I would have liked, it will certainly accomplish what I am looking for. I will try to implement something like this (likely without `BlockUI`) and get back to this thread later on. +1

Comment: @Dutchie432 If you come up with an elegant way of blocking without the BlockUI could you please share it? I'd much rather have up front code rather than a plugin. Also, glad I could help!

Comment: Actually, I am already using `jQueryUI Tools` for my modals. I believe that would work in place of BlockUI... (Demo: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/modal-dialog.html)